# Google Sheet Api V4 : Unable to fetch cell note in Google Sheet

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working with Google Sheet API. I am facing problem to read cell Note.
As below image, I am able to reading cell value i.e. "Ajay Gangwar", but not able to read cell note i.e. "Senior Software Engineer".

[image]

Below code working fine to read data from Google Sheet:

```
    private static void readGoogleSheetNote(SheetsService sheetsService)
    {
        string spreadsheetId = "1FvPaJVu5z_Vml8eIqPK7q2WOWosOH-llL4p3FItg6Zo";
        string range = "Sheet1";

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.ValueRenderOptionEnum valueRenderOption = (SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.ValueRenderOptionEnum)0;
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.DateTimeRenderOptionEnum dateTimeRenderOption = (SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.DateTimeRenderOptionEnum)0;

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest getRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
        getRequest.ValueRenderOption = valueRenderOption;
        getRequest.DateTimeRenderOption = dateTimeRenderOption;

        Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange response = getRequest.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The output of the above code is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to get the cell notes, as seen on the Overview of [Cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells) from this resource.

Using the following script you will get the data from the `A4` cell. Inside the response there is the notes field:

```
String spreadsheetId = "SPREADSHEET ID";
String range = "Sheet1!A4";
bool includeGridData = true;
SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
request.Ranges = range;
request.IncludeGridData = includeGridData;
Data.Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Sheets));
```

Comment: Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please  [accept the answer (✓)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too.